# fetch json array from webservice

Tags: json, flutter, httprequest, fetch

I am trying to fetch a json array from webservice.

The docs say:

```
_getIPAddress() {
  final url = 'https://httpbin.org/ip';
  HttpRequest.request(url).then((value) {
      print(json.decode(value.responseText)['origin']);
  }).catchError((error) => print(error));
}
```

If I use this code I get the error:

```
The method request is not defined for the class 'HttpRequest'
```

While If I try to import:

```
import 'dart:html';
```

I get this error:

```
Target of URI doesn't exist 'dart:html'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For http requests i recommend the [http package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http).

Then after importing the http package you can use it like that for example:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

_getIPAddress() async {
  final url = 'https://httpbin.org/ip';
  try {
    http.Response res = await http.get(url);
    print(json.decode(res.body));
  } catch(e) {
       print(e);    
     }     
}
```

Comment: I get the error `The argument type Response can't be assigned to the parameter type String`